# How to store hashes in ipsec.secrets when using Strongswan with eap-mschapv2?

Tags: authentication, ipsec, encryption, strongswan, eap

I am using `eap-mschapv2` as an authentication method. It requires to store plain text passwords in `ipsec.secrets`. I.e. I have a password like this:

```
user : EAP "mypassword"
```

I want to use something like this:

```
user : EAP "34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44"
```

Is it possible to change the authentication method so that I would store only hashes on the server and clients would be able to authenticate themselves by plain text passwords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic challenge-response based EAP methods (and in particular those supported by strongSwan) require access to the plaintext password to verify the client's response (EAP-MSCHAPv2 is actually an exception, see below). There are password based challenge-response authentication schemes for IKEv2 that do not require storing the plaintext password (based on zero-knowledge password proofs), e.g. AugPAKE ([RFC 6628](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6628)) or PACE ([RFC 6631](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6631)), and some EAP methods, e.g. EAP-EKE ([RFC 6124](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6124)), allow that too, but strongSwan currently does not support any of them.

An alternative is to use [EAP-GTC](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Eap-gtc), which transmits a plaintext password that allows the server to verify the password against hashes (e.g. by using [PAM](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/XAuthPAM)). The problem with that is that most clients don't support the method.

For EAP-MSCHAPv2 it is actually possible to store the password as NT-Hash (an MD4 hash of the UTF16-encoded password), see the documentation of the [NTLM keyword](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NTLMSecret) for ipsec.secrets. But that doesn't increase the security much.