# Strongswan central authentication for already exisint users in database

Tags: linux, ipsec, strongswan, radius, freeradius

I have read a lot about authenticating Strongswan to SQL/PAM but can't find any idea/solution how to authenticate against a database where already there are a plenty of username and password combination **encrypted with bcrypt+salt**.
I **don't know the plaintext passwords** so I don't understand how to start it.

I wrote a custom Radius server (used pyrad) but it is only supports PAP, which is not a good solution in nowodays. So basically, with this solution I were able to achieve my goal, but it is really not secure.
In every client I had to disable the MSCHAPv2 and enable only the PAP.

I have searched days for this, but for me it seems impossible to authenticate them without the plaintext password. Maybe i don't understand the whole process but I can't find any solution yet for my case.
Tried Freeradius with my datas from SQL but the passwords are stored differently which Freeradius expects.

Can you recommend technology/idea how to achieve this?
Somehow I want to authenticate them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly used username/password-based EAP methods (like EAP-MSCHAPv2) don't work without plaintext passwords because they use a challenge-response exchange (i.e. both client and server need the plaintext password to come to the same result when using a random challenge).

While there are EAP methods that transmit a plaintext password (e.g. EAP-GTC), which could then be checked against hashes, they are not supported by many clients. There are also modern password-based authentication schemes, based on zero-knowledge proofs, for IKEv2 and EAP that don't require storing or transmitting plaintext passwords, but they have the same issue regarding support.

Please refer to [one of my previous answers](https://serverfault.com/a/883801/95913) for details.